# SharePoint server 2016 outgoing email are failing with gmail since june 2022

Tags: sharepoint-server, outgoing-email

We have a SharePoint 2016 server, and we have setup outgoing emails using Gmail, and everything was working fine for the last few years, However, the emails suddenly stopped sending since June 2022.
I can see the emails in the queue folder.
I have tried creating App password for the gmail account and tried using that in the Delivery -> outbound security -> basic authentication settings under the SMTP properties in IIS6, still no luck.

Comment: Please provide the _complete_ configuration you're using on IIS SMTP.

Comment: I am using the exact steps as mentioned here: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/configure-outgoing-email-functionality-in-sharepoint-server-2016/

Comment: Have you created an App Password for your Gmail account? Gmail recently enforced 2FA for all accounts which prevents Basic auth from working.

https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833

Comment: I have tried App Aassword and used the app password in the basic auth